# R group locations by street

Tags: r, cluster-computing, spatial, reverse-geocoding

I have multiple (~200,000) longitude/latitude coordinates  and I would like to group them by street name. Using reverse geocoding is a solution, but it takes a long time (tried tidygeocoder).
Any other suggestions ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution .. (as  a note to myself and anyone who may get interested):
`oe_get` from `osmextract` gets the street names and geometry of the place.
Then we find the street where each of our points belongs with `st_nearest_feature` of the  `sf` package.

Comment: Maybe you could share some sample code in order to make this a more useful question/answer.